# "EmailOrderProcessor' does not implement interface member"

Tags: c#

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

> Error  1   'OnlineShoppingStore.Models.EmailOrderProcessor' does not implement interface member 'OnlineShoppingStore.Abstract.IOrderProcessor.ProcessorOrder(OnlineShoppingStore.Models.Cart, OnlineShoppingStore.Models.ShippingDetails)

Comment: Implement missing interface methods?

Comment: Please next time post code in written format

Comment: Ctrl+. (period) on that marked classname

Answer (score 2):

Interface requires the method to be called `ProcessorOrder`. You named it `ProcessOrder`